# uiwindow landscape mode problem

Tags: iphone, rotation, landscape, uiwindow

i a uiview compenent and add it to application uiwindow like below. it works fine in portrait mode but when i oriante into lanscape mode it does not work properly. it think uiwindow still feels itself in portrait mode although not. how can run in landscape mode?

thanks.

> MyView* popupView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) 
>   url:url slidingType:slidingType html5Flag:_html5Flag];
>   // i change frame to CGRectMake(0, 0,480, 320) but not works

```
[popupView setTitle:self.currentAd.altText];
popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]; 

UIWindow* mainWindow = (((UIWindow*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window);   

CGPoint middleCenter = popupView.center;   
CGSize offSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;  

CGPoint offScreenCenter = CGPointMake(offSize.width / 2.0, offSize.height * 1.5);   

popupView.center = offScreenCenter; 
[mainWindow addSubview:popupView];    
popupView.center = middleCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that you view popupView autorized to rotate ? You need yo implement this method in your UIViewController class:

```
- (void)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes i've already imlemented it in the controller in which the code posted above. but problems seems to not rotating uiwindow since i am pushing the view in it.